# Magento 2.3.0: product with quotation mark crashing

Tags: magento2.3.0, special-character

I'm trying to upgrade from Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.0.

I have the two instances side by side running the same data, and in 2.3.0 my javascript is failing on products with double quotes (") in their titles.

The javascript error I'm getting is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 80
>       at JSON.parse ()

The error is behind enough anonymous functions that I can't seem to trace it back any further, but it's definitely only products with " marks in their titles.

Additionally the product page doesn't load any further: no picture, no dropdowns, no descriptions.

Removing the quotes is not an option because there are lots of products with quotes and because it works in 2.2.6 just fine. Some change in 2.3.0 regressed and introduced this issue.

Thanks in advance!